# Unable to display array of only one object using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My Objective is to display the name which is inside the object. here is the snippet attached for your reference.[image]

it contains:

```
{
id: "12497wewrf5144",
name: "ABC",
isVisible: "false"
}
```

I have tried in this way:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      demo: {}
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('/api/random')
  .then(res => {
this.setState({demo: res.data})
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.demo.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Demo;
```

But i'm not getting the value of name.
We use map for multiple objects in array, but do we need to map even for single array?
i have tried giving like "this.state.demo[0].name", but this one also not working

Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: Is the value of the name an empty string? If it's empty, null, or undefined then it won't display.

Comment: For the reference i've wrong in that way, but the object is retrieving from backend

Comment: Can you provide a little more context how the first snippet with an array and single element object relates to the react code snippet has has an object in state and should render without issue (as far as object property access goes)?

Comment: How are you setting the fetched data from backend into the state?

Comment: @DrewReese - Hi, if i click on the arrow mark, it is showing like this: ```0: {id: "12497wewrf5144", name: "ABC", isVisible: "false"}```

Comment: @fctmolina - I've updated the code, could you please check it once?

Comment: I don't know about type script but in react you just need to initialize it as  `this.state = {
      demo: { }
    };` and you can access it as this.state.demo.name.

Comment: @NidhiDadiya - in typescript, we need to declare the variable, otherwise it will show us error

Comment: @Arunya what it shows when you put a  this.setState({demo: res.data},()=>{
        console.log(this.state.demo.name);}
      ); inside then in your service call  ?

Comment: If `res.data` is `{id: "12497wewrf5144", name: "ABC", isVisible: "false"}` and you `this.setState({ demo: res.data })` then I don't see any reason for it not to work. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: @DrewReese - res.data is `[{id: "12497wewrf5144", name: "ABC", isVisible: "false"}]` . Right now it is working great. In my code i've made mistake in displaying. `this.state.demo[0].name` is working

Comment: Then I think you should "unpack" the response when setting state, i.e. something like `this.setState({ demo: res.data?.[0] })`. The optional chaining is to ensure you don't try accessing index 0 of an empty array. This also keeps your state data type consistent.

Comment: @DrewReese: Okay, i'll use it in this way.

Comment: "how to change the value of object to true or false when we call onChange method? Could you assist me?" Yes, but in a separate question as that is a little out-of-scope here. Feel free to tag me.

Comment: @DrewReese  - I've added as a separate query. could you please assist me "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63500333/unable-to-change-the-value-in-the-object-using-reactjs"

Comment: @DrewReese - HI, Could you please assist me in my new Query - "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806499/how-to-change-number-to-string-while-submitting-the-data-using-reactjs?noredirect=1#comment112830771_63806499"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API response is like following

```
data =[
        {id: "12497wewrf5144", name: "ABC", isVisible: "false"},
        {id: "12497wewrf5255", name: "CBD", isVisible: "true"}
      ];
```

Render Response Data

```
class First extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        {id: "12497wewrf5144", name: "ABC", isVisible: "false"},
        {id: "12497wewrf5255", name: "CBD", isVisible: "true"}
      ];,
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(d => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```