# how to change number to string while submitting the data using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My objective is to change the value of variable while submitting the data.

Here is the array:

```
experiences: [
    {
        Organisation: "",
        Id: "",
        From: "",
        To: "",
        experience: "",
        Skills: []
    },
    {
        Organisation: "",
        Id: "",
        From: "",
        To: "",
        experience: "",
        Skills: []
    }
]
```

I have tried changing in Onchange by giving `value.toString()`, but while submitting it is taking `0` if we dont give any value.

So, thought to change the value while submitting the data.

Here is the handleSubmit() change:

```
handleSubmit = (e)=> {
e.preventDefault();
const lowercaseKeys = obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => [
      key.toLowerCase().replace('organisation', 'organisationName'),
      val
    ])
);
const obj = this.state.experiences.map(lowercaseKeys);
console.log("Object:", obj)
}
```

i'm not getting any idea how to change the value to string in the above object `obj`.

Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: Have you tried using a template literal?

Comment: @MasonCurtis - No, i didn't. i'm not sure where to use it

Comment: I just posted an answer. Please let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Seems to me you have 2 questions here. (1) is lowercasing and changing keys, and stringifying data for submission, and (2) changing values for submission. Can you provide an example `this.state.experiences` array, and expected output? Can you also provide clearer details about what "change the value of variable while submitting the data" means? What value(s) are you trying to change?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect solution but maybe worth giving a go.

Try using a template literal as in...

```js
let myNewStr = `${numToBeConverted}`
```

Then save `myNewStr` into the DB instead of the string.

You can also do `${numToBeConverted}` by itself.

For example:
Instead of doing `value.toString()` you'd do

```
`${value}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing val to `${val}`

> Have you tried using a template literal? – Mason Curtis